# How to split the string inputted by user

Tags: java, string, split, parseint

This is for our assignment in Java Programming. I want to know how to split an inputted string by the user.
The program will ask the user to input his birth date in `MM/dd` format. After that I want the application to split the date (delimiter is the slash). Add the number. And output the zodiac sign base on the sum of the number.

Expected result :

```
Please enter your date of birth (MM/dd): 01/06
This is the mmdd value: 106
Result: Capricorn
```

But I am not getting this result with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int mmdd;
    int a;
    int b;

   System.out.print("Please enter your date of birth(MM/dd): ");
   String stringdate = scan.next();

   a = Integer.parseInt(stringdate.split("/") [0]);
   b = Integer.parseInt(stringdate.split("/") [1]);
   mmdd = a + b;

   System.out.println("This is the mmdd value: " + mmdd);

   System.out.print("Result: ");
     if (mmdd >= 321 && mmdd <= 419) {
         System.out.println("ARIES");
     } else if (mmdd >= 420 && mmdd <= 520) {
         System.out.println("TAURUS");
     } else if (mmdd >= 521 && mmdd <= 620) {
         System.out.println("GEMINI");
     } else if (mmdd >= 621 && mmdd <= 722) {
         System.out.println("CANCER");
     } else if (mmdd >= 723 && mmdd <= 822) {
         System.out.println("LEO");
     } else if (mmdd >= 823 && mmdd <= 922) {
         System.out.println("VIRGO");
     } else if (mmdd >= 923 && mmdd <= 1022) {
         System.out.println("LIBRA");
     } else if (mmdd >= 1023 && mmdd <= 1121) {
         System.out.println("SCORPIO");
     } else if (mmdd >= 1122 && mmdd <= 1221) {
         System.out.println("SAGITTARIUS");
     } else if ((mmdd >= 1222 && mmdd <= 1231) || (mmdd >= 11 && mmdd <= 119)) {
         System.out.println("CAPRICORN");
     } else if (mmdd >= 120 && mmdd <= 218) {
         System.out.println("AQUARIUS");
     } else if (mmdd >= 219 && mmdd <= 320) {
         System.out.println("PISCES");
     }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a = Integer.parseInt(stringdate.split("/") [0]);` gives you `1`
`b = Integer.parseInt(stringdate.split("/") [1]);` gives you `6`

So in fact you are summing `1 + 6` for that you get `7` and not `106`.

Instead you can use :

```
String stringdate = scan.next();
stringdate = stringdate.replaceAll("[^\\d]+", "");//remove all non digits

mmdd = Integer.parseInt(stringdate);//then parse the result
```

If you enter `01/06` then `mmdd` return `106` and not `7`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a `sum` operator of integers with a `concat` operator for strings.
They might look the same (`+`) but they act very differently.

**In your specific case**: if you want your code to work as it is, you should leave `a` and `b` as strings (not parse them into integers), and then parse the `mmdd = a + b` string into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You code could reformat to

```java
public class Main{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse( "11/15" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd" ) );
//        month * 100 to make your function( 01/06 ) = 106
        int sum = parse.getMonthValue() * 100 + parse.getDayOfMonth();
        System.out.println( sum );
        System.out.println( Zodiac.valueFromSum( sum ) );
    }

    enum Zodiac{
        ARIES,
        TAURUS,
        GEMINI,
        CANCER,
        LEO,
        VIRGO,
        LIBRA,
        SCORPIO,
        SAGITTARIUS,
        CAPRICORN,
        AQUARIUS,
        PISCES;

        static Zodiac valueFromSum( Integer mmdd ){
            if( mmdd >= 321 && mmdd <= 419 ){
                return ARIES;
            }else if( mmdd >= 420 && mmdd <= 520 ){
                return TAURUS;
            }else if( mmdd >= 521 && mmdd <= 620 ){
                return GEMINI;
            }else if( mmdd >= 621 && mmdd <= 722 ){
                return CANCER;
            }else if( mmdd >= 723 && mmdd <= 822 ){
                return LEO;
            }else if( mmdd >= 823 && mmdd <= 922 ){
                return VIRGO;
            }else if( mmdd >= 923 && mmdd <= 1022 ){
                return LIBRA;
            }else if( mmdd >= 1023 && mmdd <= 1121 ){
                return SCORPIO;
            }else if( mmdd >= 1122 && mmdd <= 1221 ){
                return SAGITTARIUS;
            }else if( ( mmdd >= 1222 && mmdd <= 1231 ) || ( mmdd >= 11 && mmdd <= 119 ) ){
                return CAPRICORN;
            }else if( mmdd >= 120 && mmdd <= 218 ){
                return AQUARIUS;
            }else if( mmdd >= 219 && mmdd <= 320 ){
                return PISCES;
            }else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```